# Localization messages in Fluent validation (MVC3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC 3 application I am using `fluent validation`.

```
public class AccountModelValidator : AbstractValidator<AccountModel>
    {
        public AccountModelValidator()
        {
           m.NewPassword).WithMessage(Translator.Data["ConfirmPasswordValidation"]);
        }
    }
```

For localization I am using an example that I have found from [here](http://blog.kosev.net/2010/06/tutorial-create-aspnet-mvc-localization.html), but I have found that I have the same validation message for all languages.

The reason is that validator doesn't know that I have change the language.

How can I correctly do this?

Maybe I should use WithLocalizedMessage but it works only with .resx

Comment: I supose you implemented a mechanism to set up translator's locale. Did you check the translator's locale at run time? Is it correct?

Comment: yes it is correct, maube I need to write my own method WithMessage? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When the WithLocalizedMessage returns the same value for all languages, most likely the culture isn't set yet (this happens on a POST, where the action handlers haven't run yet)

Solution is to set the culture in a different location:
[Best place to set CurrentCulture for multilingual ASP.NET MVC web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226514/best-place-to-set-currentculture-for-multilingual-asp-net-mvc-web-applications)