# MVC4 date input locale

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want a simple date field input in MVC4, and the date format accepted should be based on a locale that I define (en-GB).

I don't want to use jQuery date picker or anything like that. I just want to annotate my `DateTime?` field such that it accepts dates in an en-GB date format, and displays the error message of my choice from a resource file.

I have read a number of posts here and have tried their suggestions without success

I have annotated my model property as follows

```
[Display(Name = "DateOfBirthLabel", ResourceType = typeof(ApplicantResources))]
[DataType(DataType.Date, 
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateOfBirthValidation", 
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ApplicantResources)),            
    DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

And it

1. Doesn't display the error message that I want it to display
2. Doesn't use the date format that I want it to (it accepts all American date formats)

I have also tried editing the web config to ensure the locale is set for the UI

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
</system.web>
```

I think this is a fairly basic requirement but I can't work out how to do it with MVC4. It should be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot o research I found the right answer. Just take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226514/best-place-to-set-currentculture-for-multilingual-asp-net-mvc-web-applications).
So just get rid of all you added on your web.config and the annotations in your model.