# MVC localization doesn't work on production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I've localized strings in MVC 4 view. It's very simple a view site. Two resources files in project with these properties:

Resources.resx - English strings
Resources.tr.resx - Turkish strings

Build Action: Embedded Resources
Copy To Output Directory : Do not copy
Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace: Resources

I can get string files in a view using @Resource.SomeString and everything is okay in my localhost. Shows me turkish file. But when i publish to production it only shows English strings?

Is there any code should i wrote to Controller? Am i missing something? I need help

Comment: Take a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226514/best-place-to-set-currentculture-for-multilingual-asp-net-mvc-web-applications

Comment: Your answer is sort of true. It looks for routedata which i don't have. I simply add     <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" /> to my web.config System.Web part and works like a charm. Thanks anyway