# MVC 4 Convert Hijri Date to Gregorian Date in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a multilingual MVC 4 Web Application (English, Spanish, Arabic ...), for the Internationalization part i followed [**This Tutorial**](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx), everything is fine so far, except on little detail, when choosing Arabic, all Date Data show up in Hijri (02/04/1436) when i want the Gregorian calendar, and since i need the cultureInfo to be dynamic, i can't set a default/Global Culture for the web app. is there a way to solve this issue by specifying the date to take a specific culture ?

Model

```
    [Display(Name = "EntryDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.i18n))]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
```

View

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntryDate)</td>
```

Comment: have you checked the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11064810/499930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alight i found it, thanks you all.

```
CultureInfo arSA = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
arSA.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new HijriCalendar();
var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact("29/08/1434", "dd/MM/yyyy", arSA);
```

it returns 7/7/2013

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to get the culture based on the selected option and transform the date accordingly.

```
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string shortUsDateFormatString = us.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
string shortUsTimeFormatString = us.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
```

This will help you get control over the date based on the selected option and have them displayed in your particular format.