# Resource is not working in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, multilingual

I am having a problem using languages in asp.net MVC 5. I wrote a base control to change the culture setting according to a cookie. 
the code is working on views but does not work on either controllers or Model data annotations.

the base Controller is:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["Language"] == null || !Validate.IsLanguage(Cookies.CurrentLanguageCode))
            {
                HttpCookie cookie_new = new HttpCookie("Language", "en");
                cookie_new.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                Response.SetCookie(cookie_new);

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Cookies.CurrentLanguageCode);
            }
            return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
        }
    }
```

the controller where I am receiving the Error:

```
    ViewBag.ErrorTitle = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture + "1";
    ViewBag.Description = "";
    switch (id)
    {
        case 0:
            ViewBag.ErrorTitle = Resource.Lang.ErrorTitlePageNotFound;
            ViewBag.Description = Resource.Lang.ErrorDescriptionPageNotFound;
            break;
```

and the error is:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "App_GlobalResources.Lang.resources" was correctly embedded or linked
>   into assembly at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies
>   required are loadable and fully signed.

The cookie does correctly exist, the language default set to Default which is en-US, and I have one resource file: Lang.resx

I am getting the same error on Data annotation. I wrote also a baseClass and let all the models inheriting from it but still getting the same problems.

Comment: Shouldn't cultureInfo be like "en-GB" and not just "en"? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226514/best-place-to-set-currentculture-for-multilingual-asp-net-mvc-web-applications